# fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'

Tags: git, git-svn

I've never seen this one before. I'm creating a development on a new Mac by cloning several svn repositories to local git repositories. Several pulled just fine, but one is being stubborn. They're all being pulled from the same svn server and there are no differences that I know of. I've tried to clone this one particular repository 4 times now and it's always the same result:

```
r3378 = 0b759d82e55df2e54fdbcb74859e56cc4f40eb5c (svn/trunk)
Auto packing your repository for optimum performance. You may also
run "git gc" manually. See "git help gc" for more information.
Counting objects: 11253, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11087/11087), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11253/11253), done.
Total 11253 (delta 7955), reused 0 (delta 0)
Removing duplicate objects: 100% (256/256), done.
fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'
```

None of the other output appears out of the ordinary or seems to indicate any kind of problem; the process just aborts. If I do a `git br -r`, not all of my branches appear (though it looks like my trunk and some of the branches import fine).

Has anyone ever seen this before? I need to get this repository cloned to be productive at home, but I need at least one of them maintenance branches that isn't being pulled. FWIW, the command I'm running is:

```
me@mine [project-root] $ git svn clone https://svn.myserver.com/myproject my-project --trunk=trunk --branches=branches/*/* --prefix=svn/
```

I'm running git 1.6.3.3 and svn 1.4.4, both installed via MacPorts. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I'm seeing the same problem on my Linux machine (Ubuntu 8.10) running git 1.6.3.2 and Svn 1.5.1.

**UPDATE:** This may have something to do with the SSL location. If I do a `git clone` using the internal, non-SSL URI of the repository things seem to shake out fine. That means more use of VPN than I'd like, but at least it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running into the same problem using git under MinGW on windows.

Like Rob said, it was an issue with SSL. It was working fine initially, but after awhile it just randomly broke with the `fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'` message.

Changing the repository url from `https://` to `http://` seemed to fix it.

Comment: Well, at least I'm not losing my mind. It took me a while to get there. In my case, unfortunately, I have to VPN in order to use the non-SSL variant. That part sucks, but at least I can be productive.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like when you install `git-core` via MacPorts you need to install the +svn variant, like so

`sudo port install git-core +svn`

Are you sure you did this?

Comment: Quite sure. Including the svn variant was key for me.