# Checking out an SVN repository using Git - Fatal: unable to run 'git-svn' error

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to check out a svn repository using git.

I'm using the following command:

git.exe svn clone "https://svn.outserver.net:8443/svn/someProject"

I accept the certificate, and the repository transfer starts. After a while, say 15min, I get a "fatal: unable to run "git-svn"". I have tried pulling down multiple times, but I always get this error message. (When it happens .. seems to be completely random).

Also, I cannot continue a transfer after it has failed, instead of have to delete the .git directory and start over. (Or else I get a "error: More that one value for the key svn-remote.svn.fetch").

Any suggestions, other then not using https? (I'm assuming that that's the problem).

Also I was unable to determine a solution from the following post: 
[fatal: unable to run 'git-svn'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084816/fatal-unable-to-run-git-svn)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is random it sounds like a network issue. Is the network dropping packets? Does that cause a dropped connection? Try cloning from a reliable connection. Or try making a copy closer with another tool like svnsync and clone from that. Then you'll probably have to hack a bit on git-svn so that it'll work with another repository URL...

Comment: Definitely not a network issue. GIT is the only program that is having this problem. When using Subversion instead for doing large checkouts I get no problems. Also, I have never experienced any network related problems with the current network that I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to try to checkout with [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html). It has more user-friendly auth settings. And btw much faster on Windows.